# Behavior of stack addressing and esp usage

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have this C code portion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int n, array[1000], c, d, t, e;
char step;

puts("Enter a number\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

puts("any help? [y/n]");
scanf(" %c",&step);

puts("Enter integers\n");
}
```

the corresponding assembly code of mine:

```
push prompt1
call _printf
add esp, 4        ;print and add 4 bytes to esp
push num
push sc1    
call _scanf
add esp, 8       ;scan and add 8 bytes to esp

section .data
prompt1 db "Enter a number",13,10,0
sc2     db " %c",0 ;other constants
```

And the resulting assembly code after converting the C file to NASM format in command prompt.

```
mov dword [esp], ?_001       ;?_001 is prompt1                    
call    _puts                                   
lea     eax, [esp+0FBCH]                        
mov     dword [esp+4H], eax                     
mov     dword [esp], ?_002   ;?_002 is sc1                 
call    _scanf                                  
mov     dword [esp], ?_003                  
call    _puts
```

full assembly code: http://pastebin.com/R6UHRw8x
However,I did not understand the converted assembly code because  mov dword [esp+4H], eax    uses [esp + 4] and the next line uses only [esp]. 
Shouldn't it be [esp] first then [esp + 4]? I don't understand and I saw many occurrences of it in the file.
Besides push and mov, how is the generated code different from mine regarding esp?

Comment: Unrelated to your question and just for your information: When using [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) then any white-space in the format matches any and any number of white-space in the input. So you don't need to use `"\n"` to match an enter, a normal space `" "` works just as well. And that single space matched all consecutive white-space.

Comment: `printf` has been optimized to `puts` by the compiler. Replace all your `printfs` by `puts` and try again.

Comment: Please show the **whole** assembly code of the `main` function generated by the compiler.

Comment: @MichaelWalz http://pastebin.com/DsBCxhur. lines 28-30 are what I'm trying to understand

Comment: Please replace all `printf` by `puts` (see my previois comment), then edit your question with the new code and the new compilation results mentionning **all** lines of `main` from the beginning upto the call to `scanf`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I edited the post by changing all printf to put and provided the simple and full generated assembly code

Comment: I gather your target is Windows. The stack needs to be 16-bytes aligned when making any function call. The compiler has chosen to maintain proper alignment by determining the maximum number of parameters to any function call in your `main` is 2 DWORDS. It reserves bytes needed for all your local variables plus 2 DWORDS rounded to a 16-bye boundary. The total space allocated is 4032 which is divisible by 16. The stack is manually aligned to 16 bytes upon entry to `main`. The bottom 2 DWORDS of the currently allocated stack area get used as place for function call arguments.

Comment: `push`es are avoided to maintain proper stack alignment. `mov`'s are used to put the values on the stack instead. Because `push` isn't used to place arguments on the stack (because the space is pre-allocated) it also doesn't need to `add` to esp after each call.

Comment: And lastly my guess for 16-byte alignment comes from the fact that GCC under Windows will align the stack to 16-byte boundaries, despite the fact that the Windows 32-bit ABI suggests that the stack only has to be 4-byte aligned. Your complete disassembled code suggests GCC under Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler output passes `scanf` pointers to stack space, instead of to static storage.

It lets args build up on the stack instead of popping after every call (so it can use `mov`).  Neither way avoids [inserting stack-engine synchronization uops](http://agner.org/optimize/), unfortunately.

According to the ABI/calling convention, the first arg (in C order) is at the lowest address, just above the return address.  So it's correct to put `esp+0FBCH` into `[esp+0x4]`, and the format-string pointer into `[esp]`.  See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links.

Comment: I assume that esp+0FBCH is the address of a memory cell (ex. variable). But the calling of arguments of a function is from right to left, correct me if I'm wrong. num (variable) comes first before format-string. I still think that num should be pointed by esp then esp+4 for format-string. So you mean that with mov, esp pointers can be interchangeable?

Comment: @Obito If you push from right to left, then when you're done, the first parameter is at `[esp]`.

Comment: oh, I got it now. Thanks!